# Installing gcc 4.8 on Debian

Tags: gcc, c++11, debian

I want to start playing around with some of the newer C++11 features and it appears that the best support for this is with gcc 4.8, and Squeeze ships with 4.4.5.

However, I don't want to cause any "damage" to my current setup. What's the best way to get *both* versions of gcc running side-by-side? I'm concerned mostly at the large number of dependencies and that taking them all in to my current system may render it unstable.

Has anyone managed to do this, and what are the steps involved?

Failing that, I'll probably just create a VM and run an "unstable" Debian under that but it's a less-than-ideal solution.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you install GCC from source just make sure you don't install it to `/usr` and it won't mess anything up. If you install it as your own user, not `root`, then there is zero chance of messing up the system.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC for the almost-idiot-proof minimal configuration.

I have various versions built as my user and installed in `~/gcc/4.X` for various X.

The only thing to be aware of using that set up is that the shared libraries for the new version aren't in the dynamic linker's default search path, so you need to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or some other solution to ensure executables find the libs from 4.8, see the [libstdc++ FAQ](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths) and the page it links to in the [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.dynamic)

I use a wrapper script call `g++11` which simply calls the new version of GCC with `-std=gnu++11` and passes a flag to the linker telling it to set the path to the 4.8 libs in the executable:

```
$HOME/gcc/4.8/bin/g++ -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/gcc/4.8/lib64 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -g "$@"
```

Comment: i found especially useful the wrapper script

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, and didn't want to fully upgrade to testing.

Jessie (testing) now contains g++-4.8 which is compliant with C++11.

I used apt-pinning in the following way:

A source to jessie was added to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ jessie main non-free contrib
```

/etc/apt/preferences was edited as such:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=wheezy
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: gcc*
Pin: release n=jessie
Pin-Priority: 910
```

Then,

```
$ sudo aptitude update
$ sudo aptitude install gcc/jessie
```

At which point I selected the second presented option to resolve dependencies fully.

Comment: It should be `n=jessie`, distro codename is `n=` according to `man apt_preferences`. Besides, it doesn't work for me with `a`.

Comment: These instructions break Debian 7.8.0 (wheezy) by removing the existing gcc 4.7 installation and not installing a newer gcc. It is not possible (or it does not work) to use `apt-get` to try to reinstall the original gcc 4.7, to get back to a working developer state, either.

Answer (score 6):

Debian has the package under the name gcc-4.8 (or for the c++ compiler, g++-4.8). Installing those packages will not mess up your OS, as long as you do not rename it to g++.  The package is listed as experimental though.
Information on the package is [here](http://packages.debian.org/experimental/g++-4.8).

Update: g++-4.8 is now in [testing](http://packages.debian.org/testing/g++-4.8), but an updated package is in [unstable](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/g++-4.8)

Comment: He can configure his system to find non-stable packages if he wishes though.  Look at [this question on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/questions/22414/how-can-i-run-debian-stable-but-install-some-packages-from-testing) (read the accepted answer).

Comment: Sure -- I am aware of that as I've been a Debian developer/maintainer since 1995.  It's just not for the faint-of-heart as the gap between stable and testing/unstable can get wide.  Much easier to use testing as the base, which I have been doing for years. But YMMV, and his too.

Comment: What about all the other stuff that'll get pulled in, the libraries and such? Will those co-exist okay? For example, will gcc4.5 still use the correct libc (or does that matter)?

Comment: Everything should coexist fine.  All the packages are suffixed with "-4.8" to prevent any conflicts.

Comment: `Jessie g++-4.8` although unstable but works like charm!, without any conflict! for me...

Answer (score 2):

Quick ones:

1. Just upgrade to testing, it is rock-solid and offers you several concurrent gcc versions. Similar for Ubuntu, on 12.10 I have gcc/g++ 4.4, 4.5, 4.6 and 4.7 in parallel.
2. Try the Debian backports archive, it may have a port of gcc 4.8.
3. Use virtualization: I prefer libvirt / kvm which is incredibly lightweight on Linux as it is kernel based.  My amd64 server has two other 32 bit installations for that very reason.
4. Not really a SO question...

Comment: From the FAQ: "software tools commonly used by programmers". If gcc doesn't match that description, I'll eat my hat :-)

Comment: SO is for programming, I have seen the moderator mafia move lots of similar questions over to superuser.  Personally, I _like_ the question here and think the SE sites are getting too fine-grained.  Just saying that I more or less expect this to get closed / moved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [chroot](http://wiki.debian.org/chroot) to install a newer Debian flavor?

- you can play around without fear to break you working system.
- install a Debian flavor that support you gcc version desired.
- install a gcc version manually without affecting you working system.
  [http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Chroot](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aDoc/Building_Blender/Linux/Chroot)