# Getting error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm' while porting my c++ code from linux to android

Tags: android, c++, linux, assembly

My C++ code is working fine on my Linux x86 machine but after porting the same code to Android which is running same x86 architecture I am getting error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'.

In my `android.mk` file there are two source files, one is a `.cpp` file and the other is a `.asm` file. I think the `.asm` file is not getting compiled because if I remove it from `android.mk` I still get the same error.
I am getting error on .cpp file which is below:

```
for(int reg = 0; reg <= max; reg++) {
    asm ("cpuid"
             : "=a" (eax),
               "=b" (ebx),
               "=c" (ecx),
               "=d" (edx)
             : "a" (reg), getting error on this line.
           "c" (0));
```

and if I try to compile .asm file seperatly with nasm it is compiling successfully but not with as assembler in both Linux and android.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Please tell me how to add nasm assembler on android.
my .asm file is compiling with nasm assembler but not with as.
so what should we do so that .asm file will compile with nasm assembler.i have installed nasm assembler on my x86.

Comment: which version of gcc/c++ compiler are you using? try updating it to 4.8, if your OS doesnt have stable builds, try some from testing or unstable just to proof its gcc ;) (see http://edukit.me/installing-gcc48 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311600/installing-gcc-4-8-on-debian )

Answer (score 2):

Android typically runs on the ARM architecture, and I'm going to hazard a guess that your Linux is running on x86 / AMD64, since you haven't specified that. Assembly code (which is what is almost certainly inside your .asm file) is not portable between different architectures.

You will need to replace the contents of the .asm file with code which can run on ARM. If removing that file is still giving you the same error, then look for any inline assembly code in your C++ source file. The error message (which you should always copy-paste entirely and accurately when posting questions) should specify which file and line number caused the error.

Comment: he says he uses android for x86 cpu architecture.

Comment: @mojjj No he does not, and in the absence of any other facts, it is highly likely that his Android is running on ARM.

Comment: he says: "after porting the same code to Android which is running same x86 architecture". beside, i came to the error above with an older gcc/c++ compiler version. i was on 4.7.2 and trying to compile latest OpenCV 2.4.x - looks like it should be fixed in later gcc/c++ versions, which are unfortunately not available in stable for debian wheezy (7.7)

Comment: @mojj Ah ok, I see that he has edited the question after I posted my answer. Originally, he was ambiguous about the platform.

Comment: ya, anyway, this is way old ;)