# Source-built gcc linking error

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have Debian Wheezy and I need C++11 features to build my project. I've compiled gcc(c and c++ only) from source and put the libraries under my home folder using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311600/installing-gcc-4-8-on-debian) question. I am also using the wrapper script supplied by the guy who answered that question which is

```
$HOME/gcc/gcc-4.8.4/bin/g++ -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/gcc/gcc-4.8.4/lib32 "$@"
```

Now, I have a game engine that I use in my project for GUI and graphic operations. It compiles in 32 bit just fine. I pass `-m32` switch for all of the external libraries it uses and the engine itself. Also, in order for cmake to find my wrapper, I give following options while running cmake

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=path/to/my/32-bit-wrapper
```

After compilation, it gives following linking erros

```
undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
undefined reference to `glBlendFunc'
undefined reference to `alGenBuffers'
```

At first, I thought I may be missing the 32-bit development libraries, so I installed following packages.

- libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
- libopenal-dev:i386
- libx11-dev:i386

but I am getting errors, regardless. So, How can I solve this problem? I can supply additional information such as cmake files etc if needed. Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Cmake file in case if error stems from it

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

project(uwmf)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -m32 -DLINUX")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -m32 -DLINUX")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "${HOME_PATH}/devel/g++-4.8.4-32")
#set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "${HOME_PATH}/devel/gcc-4.8.4-32")

message("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
message("${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")
message("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
message("${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(GGE ${HOME_PATH}/devel/gorgon-3.x)
set(GRAPHICS ${HOME_PATH}/devel/graphics)

set(SOURCES
  src/source.cpp
  src/algorithms.h
  src/cloud-gen.h
  src/latex.h
  src/macros.h
  src/matrix.h
  src/utils.h    
)

include_directories(${GGE})
include_directories(${GRAPHICS})

add_executable(uwmf ${SOURCES})


target_link_libraries(uwmf ${GGE}/build/libGGE.a)
```

**UPDATE**

ereOn's answer did the trick. I also had to install `libalut-dev:i386` and link (`-lalut`) to successfully compile. I get many warning messages like the following (probably due to introducing additional linkage of same library)

```
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: type of symbol `glDrawBuffers' changed from 2 to 1 in ../devel/gorgon-3.x/build/libGGE.a(OpenGL.cpp.o)
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: type of symbol `glGetAttribLocation' changed from 2 to 1 in ../devel/gorgon-3.x/build/libGGE.a(OpenGL.cpp.o)
```

but these are not part of this question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the libraries are being linked?

Comment: For XOpenDisplay you need to link to libX11 (-lX11 compiler flag), for glBlendFunc you need to link to libGL, (-lGL flag), and for alGenBuffers , link to libopenal (-lopenal flag). Are you doing that ?

Comment: These libraries are statically linked in game engine I am using (libGGE.a) with `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(GGE ${_lib})`. I compiled many programs using this engine and never needed to explicitly link x11, libgl etc.

Comment: hmm... two layers of linking sometimes means the linker will optimize out unused symbols (but this shouldn't be the case with libraries so idk). try adding them explicitly to see if it helps

Comment: `make VERBOSE=1` and show the line that causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the symbols that are reported missing are not used by your game engine library and were thus "optimized out" to make for a smaller binary.

Try linking your target executable explicitely with `-lX11` and `-lGL` to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

As @ereOn said, the linker could have optimized out some symbols. Try linking with `-Wl,--no-as-needed`.

Comment: That's the default (except with the gcc provided by Ubuntu).