# cmake configure error in 3.10.1 but not in 3.9.6

Tags: cmake, g++

I have installed cmake on a debian squeeze machine one month ago with cmake 3.9.6 and it works well.

Now, I am installing cmake on another squeeze machine, but it doesn't work when I do `./configure`.
It says :

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CMake 3.10.1, Copyright 2000-2017 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc  
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find a C++ compiler supporting C++11 on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable CXX.
See cmake_bootstrap.log for compilers attempted.
---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /home/doom/things/cmake-3.10.1/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
---------------------------------------------
```

And the logs :

```
    Checking for GNU toolchain
Try: gcc
Line: gcc  cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_28642_test
----------  file   -----------------------
int main() { return 0; }
------------------------------------------
Test succeeded
Try: g++
Line: g++  cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cpp -o cmake_bootstrap_28642_test
----------  file   -----------------------
int main() { return 0; }
------------------------------------------
Test succeeded
Checking whether 'gcc  ' works.
Try: gcc
Line: gcc   cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.c -o cmake_bootstrap_28642_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#ifdef __cplusplus
# error "The CMAKE_C_COMPILER is set to a C++ compiler"
#endif

#if defined(__sun) && __STDC_VERSION__ < 199901L
#error "On Solaris we need C99."
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  printf("%d%c", (argv != 0), (char)0x0a);
  return argc - 1;
}

------------------------------------------
1
Test succeeded
Checking whether 'g++  ' works.
Try: g++
Line: g++   cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_28642_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
#endif

#if defined(__SUNPRO_CC) && __SUNPRO_CC < 0x5140
#error "SunPro <= 5.13 mode not supported due to bug in move semantics."
#endif

class Class
{
public:
  int Get() const { return this->Member; }
private:
  int Member = 1;
};
int main()
{
  auto const c = std::unique_ptr<Class>(new Class);
  std::cout << c->Get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/unordered_map:35,
                 from cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:7:2: error: #error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member ‘Member’
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: making ‘Member’ static
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘Member’
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘c’ with no type
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:23: error: ‘unique_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:24: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
Test failed to compile
Checking whether 'g++  -std=gnu++1z' works.
Try: g++
Line: g++  -std=gnu++1z cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_28642_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
#endif

#if defined(__SUNPRO_CC) && __SUNPRO_CC < 0x5140
#error "SunPro <= 5.13 mode not supported due to bug in move semantics."
#endif

class Class
{
public:
  int Get() const { return this->Member; }
private:
  int Member = 1;
};
int main()
{
  auto const c = std::unique_ptr<Class>(new Class);
  std::cout << c->Get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++1z"
Test failed to compile
Checking whether 'g++  ' works.
Try: g++
Line: g++   cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_28642_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
#endif

#if defined(__SUNPRO_CC) && __SUNPRO_CC < 0x5140
#error "SunPro <= 5.13 mode not supported due to bug in move semantics."
#endif

class Class
{
public:
  int Get() const { return this->Member; }
private:
  int Member = 1;
};
int main()
{
  auto const c = std::unique_ptr<Class>(new Class);
  std::cout << c->Get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/unordered_map:35,
                 from cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:7:2: error: #error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member ‘Member’
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: making ‘Member’ static
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘Member’
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘c’ with no type
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:23: error: ‘unique_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:24: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
Test failed to compile
Checking whether 'g++  -std=gnu++14' works.
Try: g++
Line: g++  -std=gnu++14 cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_28642_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
#endif

#if defined(__SUNPRO_CC) && __SUNPRO_CC < 0x5140
#error "SunPro <= 5.13 mode not supported due to bug in move semantics."
#endif

class Class
{
public:
  int Get() const { return this->Member; }
private:
  int Member = 1;
};
int main()
{
  auto const c = std::unique_ptr<Class>(new Class);
  std::cout << c->Get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++14"
Test failed to compile
Checking whether 'g++  -std=gnu++1y' works.
Try: g++
Line: g++  -std=gnu++1y cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_28642_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
#endif

#if defined(__SUNPRO_CC) && __SUNPRO_CC < 0x5140
#error "SunPro <= 5.13 mode not supported due to bug in move semantics."
#endif

class Class
{
public:
  int Get() const { return this->Member; }
private:
  int Member = 1;
};
int main()
{
  auto const c = std::unique_ptr<Class>(new Class);
  std::cout << c->Get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++1y"
Test failed to compile
Checking whether 'g++  ' works.
Try: g++
Line: g++   cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_28642_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
#endif

#if defined(__SUNPRO_CC) && __SUNPRO_CC < 0x5140
#error "SunPro <= 5.13 mode not supported due to bug in move semantics."
#endif

class Class
{
public:
  int Get() const { return this->Member; }
private:
  int Member = 1;
};
int main()
{
  auto const c = std::unique_ptr<Class>(new Class);
  std::cout << c->Get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/unordered_map:35,
                 from cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:4:
/usr/include/c++/4.4/c++0x_warning.h:31:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:7:2: error: #error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member ‘Member’
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: making ‘Member’ static
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘Member’
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx: In function ‘int main()’:
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘c’ with no type
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:23: error: ‘unique_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:23: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:24: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
Test failed to compile
Checking whether 'g++  -std=gnu++11' works.
Try: g++
Line: g++  -std=gnu++11 cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_28642_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
#endif

#if defined(__SUNPRO_CC) && __SUNPRO_CC < 0x5140
#error "SunPro <= 5.13 mode not supported due to bug in move semantics."
#endif

class Class
{
public:
  int Get() const { return this->Member; }
private:
  int Member = 1;
};
int main()
{
  auto const c = std::unique_ptr<Class>(new Class);
  std::cout << c->Get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++11"
Test failed to compile
Checking whether 'g++  -std=gnu++0x' works.
Try: g++
Line: g++  -std=gnu++0x cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx -o cmake_bootstrap_28642_test
----------  file   -----------------------

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
#endif

#if defined(__SUNPRO_CC) && __SUNPRO_CC < 0x5140
#error "SunPro <= 5.13 mode not supported due to bug in move semantics."
#endif

class Class
{
public:
  int Get() const { return this->Member; }
private:
  int Member = 1;
};
int main()
{
  auto const c = std::unique_ptr<Class>(new Class);
  std::cout << c->Get() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:7:2: error: #error "Compiler is not in a mode aware of C++11."
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: ISO C++ forbids initialization of member ‘Member’
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: making ‘Member’ static
cmake_bootstrap_28642_test.cxx:19: error: ISO C++ forbids in-class initialization of non-const static member ‘Member’
Test failed to compile
```

But it works well on the same machine with cmake 3.9.6.

g++ version is `gcc version 4.4.5 (Debian 4.4.5-8)`.
Latest available on my mirror.

Is it really a problem with g++ version or a problem with new version of cmake ?

If necessary, [How can I install g++ compiler from sources?](https://superuser.com/questions/1278413/how-can-i-install-g-compiler-from-sources)

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### [Since v3.10 onwards CMake is implemented in C++11](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/release/3.10.html#deprecated-and-removed-features):

> #### Deprecated and Removed Features
>
> Support for building CMake itself with C++98 compilers was dropped. CMake is now implemented using C++11.

This requires a capable compiler. The first version of GCC which is **C++11 feature complete** is [***GCC 4.8.1***](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11).

Gcc 4.4.5 is *over 7 years old* and more important, it doesn't support C++11 (from the error):

> Cannot find a C++ compiler supporting C++11 on this system.

---

#### Compiler update

As noted above, you need *at least* GCC 4.8.1. Here are some guides:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC
- [Installing gcc 4.8 on Debian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311600/installing-gcc-4-8-on-debian)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112157/how-can-i-install-more-recent-versions-of-software-than-what-debian-provides
- https://nosemaj.org/debian-gcc-4-7

Comment: g++ support some features, but not all [features from C++11](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `cmake 3.9.6` worked perfectly to build `libssh` on legacy Linux with `gcc 4.2.3` & `gcc 4.4.3`

Answer (score 0):

to choose the latest version of the gcc compiler

```
dpkg -l gcc*
```

for example install the gcc-5 version and make it the default

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5
```